# How can we add a delimiter to file with alphanumeric output so that we can delimit fixed width of the rows

Tags: awk

```
cat file1

024170529s18687522049000005000011868443700001479N
```

How can we add delimiter `,` at fixed width to the file rows?

3digitfield,6digitfield,12digitfield,10digitfield,14digitfield,3digitfield,1digitfield

Comment: and what's your desired result?

Comment: this file should have fixed width for its rows

Comment: unclear, what width size?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: 3digitfield,6digitfield,12digitfield,10digitfield,  ,14digitfield,3digitfield,1digitfield

Comment: 3digitfield,6digitfield,12digitfield,10digitfield,14digitfield,3digitfield,1digitfield

Comment: that should be in your question, not within comments

Comment: and how those characters should be treated `s` and `N` ?

Comment: thanks, will keep that in mind also the are many thousand rows in the files and system generated daily

Comment: s and N are part of the Data that gets generated some should be treated as part of the data in that fixed width

Comment: just take your input string and show its transformed version (at start)

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk and `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 6 12 10 14 3 1";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' file
024,170529,s18687522049,0000050000,11868443700001,479,N
```

**Edit**: awk version:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    fw="3 6 12 10 14 3 1"
    n=split(fw,a)
    OFS="," 
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,p+1,a[i]), (i<n? OFS : ORS)
        p+=a[i] }
}' file
024,170529,s18687522049,0000050000,11868443700001,479,N
```

Comment: Thanks lots James, seems some syntax still need fixing

Comment: system OP17:09:10 [mau-bss-app:/opt/redknee/dist/TEST_export_TPS]$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 6 12 10 14 3 1";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' new.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: GNU awk only, which awk are you using?

Comment: Im on a solaris machine, seems it is not taking the gawk command also

Comment: 17:14:29 [mau-bss-app:/opt/redknee/dist/TEST_export_TPS]$ gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 6 12 10 14 3 1";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' new.txt
bash: gawk: command not found
17:15:48 [mau-bss-app:/opt/redknee/dist/TEST_export_TPS]$

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: @Sonny any time you see the error message `awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1` it means you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk - get GNU awk (gawk) or if you can't then use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris instead.